# C# Async Oauth API Wrapper Class

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-web-api

Two quick notes: I'm targeting 4.5, and the server already has newtownsoft's json library. I'd prefer not installing anything additional on the server.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;

namespace Sierra
{
    public class API
    {
        private string _uri, _key, _secret, _token;
        private DateTime _token_expires;
        public bool isInitialized = false;
        private static HttpClient Client = new HttpClient();

        #region Classes for json serializer

        //POCO classes for serializer

        #endregion

        /// <summary>
        /// initialize the API
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="uri">Base uri to API endpoint</param>
        /// <param name="key">Key value </param>
        /// <param name="args">Secret value</param>
        public API(string uri, string key, string secret)
        {
            _uri = uri;
            _key = key;
            _secret = secret;
            isInitialized = GetBearerTokenAsync().Result;
        }

        public Patron GetPatronById(string barcode)
        {
            string uri = String.Format("patrons/find?barcode={0}", barcode);
            var Patron = GetAsync<Patron>(uri).Result;

            return Patron;
        }

        public Boolean PlaceHold(int patronID, string recordType, int recordNumber, string pickupLocation)
        {
            string uri = String.Format("patrons/{0}/holds/requests", patronID);

            Hold hold = new Hold();
            hold.recordType = recordType;
            hold.recordNumber = recordNumber;
            hold.pickupLocation = pickupLocation;
            string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(hold);

            HttpResponseMessage response = PostAsync(uri, json).Result;

            return response.IsSuccessStatusCode == true;
        }

        public async Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string uri)
        {
            CheckToken();
            var content = await Client.GetStringAsync(uri);
            var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var t = serializer.Deserialize<T>(content);

            return t;
        }

        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostAsync(string uri, string json)
        {
            CheckToken();
            var response = await Client.PostAsync(uri, new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
            return response;
        }

        private async Task<bool> GetBearerTokenAsync()
        {
            var client      = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(_uri);
            var request     = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "/iii/sierra-api/v2/token");

            var byteArray   = new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(_key + ":" + _secret);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));

            var formData    = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
            formData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "client_credentials"));
            request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(formData);

            var response    = await client.SendAsync(request);
            var payload     = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            SierraResponse SierraResponse = ser.Deserialize<SierraResponse>(payload);

            _token_expires  = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(SierraResponse.expires_in);
            _token          = SierraResponse.access_token;
            client.Dispose();
            //use static HttpClient for all subsequent requests
            InitializeHttpClient();

            return true;
        }

        internal void InitializeHttpClient()
        {
            Client.BaseAddress = new Uri(_uri);
            Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + _token);
        }

        internal void CheckToken()
        {
           if (DateTime.Now >= _token_expires)
            {
                isInitialized = GetBearerTokenAsync().Result;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Concerns

1. Is async done correctly

Comment: Welcome to code review. We can review the code, and probably answer #3, but #1 and #2 are beyond the scope of what code review is about. These are design issues, and need to fit into your system. Please see http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`API` class should be `Api` and probably `sealed`. Also `Api` isn't a meaningful name, it's an API for...what?

Fields `_uri`, `_key` and `_secret` are initialized only in ctor, make them `readonly`.

`HttpClient` is not thread-safe unless you call static methods, do not make it `static` (do not forget to implement `IDisposable` in your class). If you're concerned about resources usage then add a lock. .

No need to set `_isInitialized` to `false` because inside constructor you already set it.

You have a local variable named `Patron`, it's confusing because it has same name as `Patron` class and usually C# local variables are camelCase.

I'm not sure about `barcode` parameter content but it's not escaped, are you sure it contains only valid URL characters?

`== true` in `response.IsSuccessStatusCode == true` is unnecessary.

Why do you have a local `HttpClient` variable? Don't you use class field? Also do not call `Dispose()` directly but use `using()`, it will correctly dispose resources also in case of errors.

`GetBearerTokenAsync()` always returns `true`, no need for a return value then make it `Task`.

Is there a reason some methods are `internal` instead of `private`?

`GetBearerTokenAsync()` does too many things, I'd refactor out some methods (convert key, send request, parse and so on).

Also you're using `DateTime.Now` as expiration, did you consider that time may change during the day (for example when changing to Summer Time), you'd better to use UTC time (which is unaffected by these changes) or your token may have birth already expired (or expire one hour later than expected).

Comment: [About HttpClient and IDisposable](http://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/).

Comment: @BCdotWEB I agree (for usage pattern is linked article) but here we have no hint about its usage. It may be concurrent (and I usually do not want to rely on an implementation detail like that...) however if it's a class member it will have the same lifespan of your class (and it will be disposed correctly when class is deleted).

Comment: (I forgot but nice link anyway, OP has to also consider that in his own usage scenario!)

Answer (score 4):

Do not use a public field; instead, make it a property:

```
public bool isInitialized = false;
```

---

Your code is barely above 100 lines, you don't need `region`s and [you shouldn't use them anyway](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53114/123339).

---

Local variables like `var Patron` should be camelCase.

---

Don't use `Boolean`, etc., instead use the alias (`bool`,...).

---

This:

```
        Hold hold = new Hold();
        hold.recordType = recordType;
        hold.recordNumber = recordNumber;
        hold.pickupLocation = pickupLocation;
```

... can be compacted to:

```
        var hold = new Hold 
        {
           recordType = recordType,
           recordNumber = recordNumber,
           pickupLocation = pickupLocation
        }
```

---

You're inconsistent in using `var`. For instance:

```
JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
```

If you'd called it javaScriptSerializer instead:

```
var javaScriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
```

---

The flow of `GetBearerTokenAsync()` jumps around a lot. You define `request` on line 3, yet don't use until line 10. Instead, you continue building `client`.